# Why the program is not showing any output?

Tags: java

I have been trying to troubleshoot this java program from hours now and has not been able to find what is wrong with the execution. I think that the main class is not defined correctly.

It compiles successfully but the output is blank which should not be the case right? I intially tried to call the main class using the objects but still no luck. Any suggestions will work.

The original program:It compiles successfully on adding the main method but the output is blank.

```java
import java.lang.Math; // headers MUST be above the first class

// one class needs to have a main() method
public class OrdSetSimple
{
  // arguments are passed using the text field below this editor
  public static void main(String[] args){

      OrdSetSimple obj = new OrdSetSimple(10);
      System.out.print("Success");

  }


  private int _set_size;
  private int _set[];
  private int _last;


  public OrdSetSimple(int size) {
    int k;
    _set_size=size;
    _set = new int[_set_size];
    for(k=0; k<_set_size; k++)
        _set[k]=0;
    _last=-1;
  }

  private int make_a_free_slot(int val) {
    int pos, i, j;

      pos = binSearch(val);
    if (pos >= 0)
        return -1;
    for (i=0; i<=_last; i++) {
        if (_set[i] > val)
            break;
    }

    if ((i<=_last)||(_last==-1)) {
        for (j=_last; j>=i; j--)
            _set[j+1] = _set[j];
        pos = i;
    } else {
            pos = _last+1;
    }
      _last++;
    return pos;
  }

  public void addElement(int n) {
    int pos;
      if (n<0) {
          System.out.println("Addition of a negative integer impossible\n");
        return;
      }
    if (_last+1>=_set_size) {
        System.out.print("Addition of " + n);
      System.out.println(" impossible since the array is already full");
          System.out.println("The array is: " + toString());
    } else {
          pos = make_a_free_slot(n);
        if (pos>=0)
            _set[pos]=n;
    }
    return;
  }

  public int getSize() {
    return _last+1;
  }

  public int getElementAt(int i) {
    if ((i<0)||(i>_last))
        return -1;
    else
        return _set[i];
  }

  private int binSearch(int x) {
    int i=0;
      int j=_last-1;
    int m=0;

    if (_last==-1)
        return -1;

    while(i<j) {
        m= (i+j)/2;
        if (x>_set[m])
            i=m+1;
        else
            j=m;
    }
    if (x == _set[i]) return i;
    else return -1;
  }

  public OrdSetSimple difference(OrdSetSimple s2) {
    OrdSetSimple s1 = this;
    int size1=s1.getSize();
    int size2=s2.getSize();

    OrdSetSimple set=new OrdSetSimple(size2);

    int k;

    for(k=0; k<size1; k++)
        if (s2.binSearch(s1.getElementAt(k)) < 0)
            set.addElement(s1.getElementAt(k));

    return set;
  }

  public String toString() {
    int k = 0;
    String s="";

    for (k=0; k<=_last; k++)
        s += _set[k] + " ";

    return s;
  }

}
```

Comment: Is this your actual code? Because it should be `System.out.print("whatever");`.

Comment: looks like you are compiling the project with entry point in the main method of the OrdSetSimple  class... since that method is empty, the app is running, doing nothing and existing without any failure or msg printed....

Comment: What "main class" are you referring to?  The only class you've posted is `OrdSetSimple`, and its main *method* is empty (and hence will print nothing).  What class does the other main method you've posted belong to?

Comment: I tried to run the original code and the compilation failed saying that I am missing some main class and should add the main method

Comment: `OrdSetSimple obj = new OrdSetSimple();` there is no such constructor in your class.

Comment: i need to run the original program..any suggestions will work

Comment: OrdSetSimple class has no constructor  `public OrdSetSimple()` and you are creating an object of `OrdSetSimple` class `OrdSetSimple obj = new OrdSetSimple();`. Implement such a constructor or remove `public OrdSetSimple(int size)` this constructor.

Comment: @AntonH i understand the sarcasm but still i'm 16 years old and new to programming..i hope you try to keep ur demeaning comments to urself and don't comment if u really can't answer

Comment: Where exactly was the demeaning/sarcastic comment? All I can see is trying to help(?)

Comment: @SQEnthusiast It wasn't sarcasm. I was asking because you weren't providing actual executable code. And if you have that as a mistake because of copying your code into SO, we need to be sure that you didn't make other mistakes copying in the rest of your code which would make helping you harder.

Comment: @LW001 It's fine, I could have been a bit more verbose in explaining why I asked the question.

Comment: @AntonH well this was the whole class..when i ran it..the compiler stated the following error [link](http://tpcg.io/5HwZwW) so i defined the main method but the program was not showing any output? that's it..i am new to java so probably i may not be making any sense..!!

Comment: You can see the error in the link above..hope u can get my point

Comment: @SQEnthusiast I follow the link and click on the execute button, and it does display an error message about the `main` method being missing. But then I add your `main`, literally as is, without modifications, and then re-execute, and it displays "Success". The actual class displays nothing, because you only call the constructor. But I apparently am not getting the same behaviour as you are, as it displays "Success" for me.

Comment: It displays"success" for me too but that's not the point of the program..what modifications should be made to the program in the link above so that the output is shown.. that's my only question..hope u know understood what I have been trying to say

Comment: @AnthonH  Can u make any valid modifications to the program in the link so the output is displayed .?

Comment: @SQEnthusiast It's not displaying anything else because you're not calling any of the methods. To call a method, you have to, from the instantiated class (in this case, `obj`), followed by a dot (`.`), followed by the method name (e.g.: `toString`). So `obj.toString();`. After that, it's calling the methods in the right order with the right parameter values to get the result you want. I am not going to do that for you, because that falls into "doing your work for you" territory, and not an issue with your actual code.

Comment: Yeah thnx @AnthonH

Comment: @AntonH hi..sry to bother u again..but can u tell me what is wrong with the difference method in the code above? i'm facing difficulty understanding that

Answer (score 1):

Your very first statement is wrong.

```
 OrdSetSimple obj = new OrdSetSimple();//This will call the default constructor which will not initialize anything. This constructor will be added to your program by compiler, hence you don't get any compilation error.
```

Correct it like

```
 OrdSetSimple obj = new OrdSetSimple(100);
```

Comment: Can you pass 5 instead of 1 and check.

Comment: Please check the edit, the compilation is successful but the output is empty

Comment: The best thing to learn programming is to debug the code, instead of asking some one to fix it. put break points in all the methods including constructor and run it on debug mode. Use eclipse to debug.

Comment: Wish you all the very best.